# Riemann integration of a function

Tags: proof-verification, riemann-integration

I would like to ask if the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}0\text{ if } x\in \mathbb{\mathbb{[0,1]}\cap Q}\\ x^2\text{ if } x\in \mathbb{[0,1]\setminus Q} \end{cases}$ is Riemann Integrable in $[0,1]$?

My thought:

Let $S(f,P)$ and $s(f,P)$ be the upper and low sums of $f$ with respect to partition $P$ of interval $[0,1]$. Let $M_i=\sup\{f(x)| x \in I_i\}$ and $m_i=\inf\{f(x)| x \in I_i\}$, where $I_i$ is the $i$th interval of the partition $P$. Note that $M_i=1$ for all $i$, because every interval $I_i$ of the partition $P$ contains rational numbers. On the other hand, $m_i=0$ for all $i$ because every interval $I_i$ of the partition $P$ contains irrational numbers. By definition,
$$S(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^nM_i\mu(I_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n1\mu(I_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n\mu(I_i)=1-0=1$$
$$s(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^nm_i\mu(I_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n0\mu(I_i)=0$$
Thus, $f$ is not Riemann integrable because the upper and lower integrals are not equal. (The upper integral is the limit of the upper sums and the lower integral is the limit of the lower sums).

Comment: You're very close, but your calculation of $M_i$ is wrong. For instance if $I_1=[0,1/\sqrt{2}]$ then $M_1=1/2$, rather than (as you claim) $M_1=1$.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not Riemann-integrable, but your computations are not correct. You are right when you claim that $s(f,P)=0$, for each partition $P$ of $[0,1]$. However, it is not true that $S(f,P)=1$ for each partition $P$ of $[0,1]$. Actually, it is not true that “$M_i=1$ for all $i$, because every interval $I_i$ of the partition $P$ of $[0,1]$ contains rational numbers”.  However, it is true that, for each partition $P$ of $[0,1]$, $S(f,P)\geqslant\frac13$, and this is enough to prove what you want.

Comment: I get confused, can you give a complete solution by the beginning please? It would be very helpful for me. Thank you

Comment: What is confusing you? You wrote that each $M_i$ is equal to $1$, which is just wrong. If $P=\left\{0,\frac12,1\right\}$, then you have two intervals: $I_1=\left[0,\frac12\right]$ and $I_2=\left[\frac12,1\right]$. In this case, $M_2$ is indeed $1$, but $M_1=\frac14$.

Comment: It would be helpful for me to have a complete solution, I am studying Riemann integration and I try to understand it. It would help me a lot

Comment: There is no way I will write anything else if you do not answer my question.

Comment: I can't see a question from you. I just ask for a help, if you have time just let me understand

Comment: Don't you see that two comments ago I asked “What is confusing you?”

Comment: I had a wrong thought. You wrote if we have two intervals etc, then $M_1=\frac{1}{4}.$ Then? If we have more intervals? I got confused

Comment: What I wrote was that **if** $P=\left\{0,\frac12,1\right\}$, then $I_1=\left[0,\frac12\right]$ and that, in **that** case,$$M_1=\sup\left\{f(x)\,\middle|\,x\in I_1\right\}=\frac14<1.$$